# Android - Retrieve and use views position in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment with 4 buttons. I want to save each button's position on screen in a hash-map (each button will be mapped to its position on screen). What is the easiest way of doing it?
Before using fragments, I used the onWindowFocusChanged method (in Activity) in which I could retrieve the button position. With fragments I tried to use ViewTreeObserver (with GlobalLayoutListener). Inside the anonymous class I can retrieve and save (in instance variable) the button position but outside of it these values are gone (equal 0).
How can it be done?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** added a code snippet -

```
public void getViewsPosition(final ArrayList<View> viewArr) {
    for (final View v : viewArr) {
        final ViewTreeObserver vto = v.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                int[] i = new int[2];
                v.getLocationOnScreen(i);
                _rect = new Rect(i[0], i[1], i[0] + v.getWidth(), i[1]
                        + v.getHeight());
                view_to_rect.put(v, _rect);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
                    vto.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    vto.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "size of view to rect = " + String.valueOf(view_to_rect.size()));
}
```

where viewArr is an arrayList of all my views in this layout ; view_to_rect is an instance variable declared as:

private static Map view_to_rect = new HashMap();

The Log always shows "size of view to rect = 0".

attached also the implementation of onViewCreated:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onViewCreated");
    final ViewGroup _mainView = (ViewGroup) getView().findViewById(
            R.id.fragment01);
    getAllViews(viewsList, _mainView);
    Log.i(TAG, "size of view list = " + String.valueOf(viewsList.size()));
    getViewsPosition(viewsList);
}
```

from where getViewsPosition is called.

**Edit#2:**
I'll try to clarify my intentions. I'm building app with fragment. each fragment, let's say, has 4 buttons. I want these buttons to listen to touch events so as the user touches a button and moves his finger to another button (without lifting his finger) there will be an audio feedback of the button's name. For that I need to have all buttons positions so to be able to identify moving from one button to another (in onTouch method). And for that I need an instance variable which will keep all buttons positions on screen and I will be able to use it in onTouch. The solution you suggested does not solve the problem because outside of

public void getViewsPosition(final ArrayList viewArr)

the size of view_to_rect is still 0.

**Edit #3:**

Here is the process in which I try to build my collection:

1) Class signature + collection and array definition:

```
public class Fragment01 extends Fragment implements OnTouchListener,
    OnClickListener{
        private Map<View, Rect> view_to_rect = new HashMap<View, Rect>();
        ArrayList<View> viewsList = new ArrayList<View>();
```

2) onViewCreated implementation:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onViewCreated");
    final ViewGroup _mainView = (ViewGroup) getView().findViewById(
            R.id.fragment01);
    getAllViews(viewsList, _mainView);
    Log.i(TAG, "size of view list = " + String.valueOf(viewsList.size()));
    getViewsPosition(viewsList);
    Log.i(TAG, "size of view to rect = " + String.valueOf(view_to_rect.size()));
}
```

3) getViewsPosition(...) and onPositioUpdate() methods -

```
public void getViewsPosition(final ArrayList<View> viewArr) {
    for (final View v : viewArr) {
        final ViewTreeObserver vto = v.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                int[] i = new int[2];
                v.getLocationOnScreen(i);
                _rect = new Rect(i[0], i[1], i[0] + v.getWidth(), i[1]
                        + v.getHeight());
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
                    vto.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    vto.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }

                onPositionUpdate();
            }
        });
    }
}

private void onPositionUpdate() {
}
```

The first Log in onViewCreated(...) is "size of view list = 7".

My question is how can I get the second log print out "size of view to rect  = 7" ? it always returns 0.

I didn't really, probably, understand how to use your solution with onPositionUpdate() method. How should it be implemented in order to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

ViewTreeObserver will be notify only when the view is rendered,
What do you you mean by

> "but outside of it these values are gone"

You can just get the positions of buttons in the GlobalLayoutListener callback, and save it the instance.**Remember, you can only get the positions on rendered.**

**REMIND:**

put this code

Log.i(TAG, "size of view to rect = " + String.valueOf(view_to_rect.size()));

inside the public void onGlobalLayout() {}, then you will get non-zero.

**Why:**

Only the onGlobalLayout method is called, you can get non-zero.

```
         public void onGlobalLayout() {
                int[] i = new int[2];
                v.getLocationOnScreen(i);
                _rect = new Rect(i[0], i[1], i[0] + v.getWidth(), i[1]
                        + v.getHeight());
                view_to_rect.put(v, _rect);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
                    vto.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    vto.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }

                onPositionUpdate();

            }

private void onPositionUpdate()
{
    //do your work with positions
}
```

Comment: I want to loop over all these buttons and save their position in some collection. I want to be able to use this collection in other methods of the class, but its (the collection) size is always 0. 
How can I do it?

Comment: At what timing did you use the collection ? You will get zero before the GlobalLayoutListener call back is called.

Comment: post some code snippet to demonstrate how you are using the collection?

Comment: kevinhoo - That's right. But - I want to access this collection from other class methods. There I get size of 0, too. Is there any possibility to access view_to_rect outside of this method and get its desired size (in this example the size suppose to be 7)?

Comment: It is about timing. There is not another way to know the exact position before the view hierarchy is rendered. You can call some method of a custom-listener to notify the outside after you get the position.

Comment: Can you please help me and tell me how to do this? where do I have to add the relevant lines? 
Thank you!

Comment: the view_to_rect will have non-zero value when the view tree is rendered. it is asyn callback. you will get zero at the beginning, but you will get it non-zero right after the view is rendered. according to your requirement, it OK that you get this position after rendered.

Comment: Probably I have some misunderstanding. In your solution you mean that onPositionUpdate() will be defined as a class method. What does this give me? how can I update by that the "view_to_rect" collection so this variable will be available (and correct) from every class method? I assume i didn't understand your solution. Would appreciate a short explanation. Thanks again!

Comment: did you write code to try my solution? please post more code to clarify how you use the view_to_rect

Comment: hmm. do you know that, your second log code, will run before the method onGlobalLayout() is called? because the latter is a call back function only when the view is rendered.

Comment: how did you solve the problem? and if you like the answer, please vote and accept it,LOL..